# Bootstrap 3 Form in Zf2

Tags: zend-framework2, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i use `Bootstrap 3` in Zend Framework 2.2.4? 
I mean the `textfields` or `textareas`. https://bitbucket.org/dlu/dlutwbootstrap doesn't work :(. At the Internet i found this Snippet but it doesn't work, too.

```
$formRenderer = $this->formRenderer($form, 'renderer.bootstrap', 'horizontal');
```

-> http://reverseform.modo.si/form/test-bootstrap

Comment: Check the version of dlutwbootstrap : this is currently not compatible with BS3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are looking for something better than just adding `form-control` perhaps look at:

https://github.com/neilime/zf2-twb-bundle

I've been using it recently and for the most part it is working great. It is also actively maintained unlike `dlutwbootstrap`.

Answer (score 3):

To be a little more specific than the "just add form-control" solutions, here is the syntax to set the class for any given Zend form element (Element\Text, etc):

`$element->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');`

I would have put this in a comment but I don't have the reputation yet. Yay StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2):

ok i have found the solution by self.
Just add the Class `form-control` to a form field.